# How fast are Ladybug and Cat Noir?

Tags: miraculous-ladybug

At various points on the show, it's stated (and also shown) that Ladybug, Cat Noir, and the other superheroes are physically more adept than the average human (to say nothing of the average high -school student): stronger, faster, tougher. How fast are they, though?

I doubt there are concrete numbers, but their speed has undoubtedly been demonstrated somehow with all the villains they chase. In general terms, how fast can they move? Faster than an athletic human, a bicycle, a car?

Comment: Why do you say "physically more adept than the average human (to say nothing of the average high -school student)"?  It seems to me that while various humans may reach the height of their physical abilities and then start to decline at various widely different ages, the high school ages are likely to include the time to reach the peak of physical abilities and then start declining for many and perhaps most humans.  As fake Finnegan said to 33? year old Kirk in "Shore Leave": "I'm still 20 years old, you're an old man."

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Muscle strength peaks at around [25 years on average.](http://www.sportsci.org/encyc/agingex/agingex.html) They're like 15 years old. Esse quam videri.

Comment: As another example, Mendez-Villanueva et al studied performance of soccer players on 10 and 20 meter sprints as a function of age. 18 year old players were faster on average than 16-year-olds. Or, Bahar Ates found that players 18-19 were faster than those 17-18.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - That is, it might seem that humans peak in their physical abilities at high school age, but they don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this clip from "Copycat", Cat Noir runs from the centre of the Louvre (across the rooftop) and to the Metro entrance at the Louvre Rivoli, a straight-line distance of approximately 350M, in just 15 seconds (23m/s or **51mph**).

Factoring in jumping and evading time, this makes him **at least twice as fast as the fastest (normal) human.**

[image]

And in this clip, Ladybug covers a distance of 41M in just 2.1 seconds, giving her a **top speed of at least 41mph**, well in advance of the top speed of a sprinting olympic athlete.

[image]

Comment: Please note that their speed is displayed inconsistently. At the end of the first clip, Cat Noir runs into the metro station so fast that the camera can only see a blur.

Comment: The blur effect just looks like artistic style to me.

Comment: @Adamant - On a purely personal note, I'd like to congratulate the show's artists for their accuracy in drawing these buildings and road features. Accurate down to the scuffing on the paint.

Comment: Heh, if I were them I wouldn't draw them at all, if possible. I'd start with some 3D scan of the area like Google Maps and "animify" it. Maybe that's why it looks so accurate.